# Total or partial order relation

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given R$\subseteq Z^2 \cap Z^2$ defined by (a,b)R(c,d) $\Leftrightarrow$ a$<$ c or a=c, b$\le$d . I have proved it's a partial order relation.

My question is how can I prove if it's total order ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know it's a partial order, all that remains to show is that is that every two elements are comparable.

Let $(a,b), (c,d) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$.

Case 1: $a \neq c$, then either $a <c$ or $ c < a$, so either $(a,b)R(c,d)$ or $(c,d)R(a,b)$, meaning they are comparable.

Case 2: $a=c$. It's a general fact that given any two real numbers $b,d$, either $b \leq d$ or $d \leq b$. Then  $(a,b)R(c,d)$ or $(c,d)R(a,b)$, meaning they are comparable.